# Vue pass data from parent to child component using props?

Tags: vue.js

How do i get `topicCategories` in the child component.  I tried using states below but it is always the previous page `topicCategories` not the current page.

Parent (post.vue)

```
export default class MyPost extends mixins(LocaleMixin) {
  Categories: any[] = [];
  topicCategories: any[] = [];

  async mounted() {
    this.loading = true;
    await this.$apiRequest(
      async () => {
        const {
          data: {
            id,
            topicCategories,
          },
        } = await this.$services.topic.fetchTopic(
          this.$route.params.slug,
          this.currentLocale.name
        );
        this.Categories = topicCategories as ICategory[];
        this.topicCategories = this.Categories.map((category: any) => category.id);
        this.$store.dispatch('app/setCurrentCategories', topicCategories);

      },
      () => {
        this.$nuxt.error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'err message' });
      }
    );
    this.loading = false;
  }

}
```

Child Component (readnext.vue)

```
export default class ReadNext extends mixins(LocaleMixin) {
  offset = 0;
  total = 0;
  topics = [];

async fetch() {
    await this.$apiRequest(async () => {
 
    if(this.$store.state.app.currentCategories.length) {

        const categories = this.$store.state.app.currentCategories.map((category: any) => category.id);
      
        const { data } = await this.$services.topic.fetchReadNext(
            categories,
            this.currentLocale.name,
            10,
            this.offset * 10
        );

        //@ts-ignore
        this.topics.push(...data.rows);

        this.total = data.count;

        this.offset += 10;
        }
    });
  }
}
```

How do i get `this.topicCategories` from the parent to the child component without using states?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare topicCategories as a prop and then pass its value into a template. Here is how to do it:
Child:

```js
import { Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';
export default class ReadNext extends mixins(LocaleMixin) {
   @Prop({default: [], required: true}) topicCategories!: any[];
   ...
}
```

Parent:

```html
<child :topicCategories="topicCategories" />
```